# Best derailleur compatible with 1.7 pull ratio?

Tags: mountain-bike, shimano, derailleur-rear, upgrades

I want to replace my Tourney 7spd with something else, but my cassette isn't compatible with an upgrade to anything else, so 7spd is what I have to stick with.

I know I have to stay within the 1.7x pull ratio, so what's the best derailleur I can get for my money that can replace my Tourney derailleur? Chain retention hasn't been a major issue, but I'd prefer a more accurate and faster derailleur.

Comment: Welcome to Bicycles SE.  You actually have two questions here.  Please split them up into two distinct questions.

Comment: Do you have a cassette or a freewheel?   Any upgrade beyond 7 speed will likely require a replacement wheel hub capable of holding a cassette.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Welcome to Bicycle Stack Exchange.
Regarding your derailleur upgrade question. Prior to mountain bike 10 speed systems, all Shimano rear derailleurs, whether marketed for road or mountain bikes, had the same actuation ratio of 1.7.  Actuation ratio is the amount of lateral rear derailleur movement per mm of cable pulled by the shifter. So, in a broad sense, any Shimano 7,8, or 9 speed rear derailleur (both road and mountain), plus 10 speed road rear derailleurs* will work in any Shimano 7, 8 or 9 speed drivetrain with an appropriate Shimano shifter, which matches the speed class of the cassette. In your case, any 7, 8, or 9 speed Shimano derailleur (road or mountain) will work in your 7 speed system (given you use a Shimano 7 speed shifter and a 7 speed cassette or freewheel).

Using [the latest line-up from Shimano](https://productinfo.shimano.com/#/spec/MTB/Rear%20Derailleur), we can see that for 7 speed, only the Tourney class is marketed for 7 speed.  However, using the actuation ratio facts described above, one can see that Acera, Altus, and Alivo class rear derailleurs, which are marketed as 8 and 9 speed will work perfectly for you. These model numbers are RD-M3100 (Alivo), RD-M2000 (Altus), RD-M370 (Altus), RD-M3020 (Acera 8 speed).

Keep in mind this only represents the newest offerings from Shimano.  The mid-level and upper tier mountain derailleurs, such a Deore, Deore XT, and XTR, currently are 11 and 12 speed systems, but they all had a history of being 7, 8 and 9 speed systems. If you can find a gently used or new-old-stock offering from one of these levels (must be marketed as 7, 8 or 9 speed), which can frequently be found on sites like eBay, Facebook Marketplace, etc, any of these would be a significant upgrade from even today's Tourney class.

The second question regarding your rear cogs has two aspects to the answer.  First you need to determine if your seven speed cogset is a "freewheel" or a "cassette." See [this Park Tool tutorial](https://www.parktool.com/en-us/blog/repair-help/determining-cassette-freewheel-type#:%7E:text=If%20the%20fittings%20spin%20with,is%20a%20threaded%20freewheel%20system.)An easy way to determine this is to spin your cogset backwards while you focus on the center of the cogset--the area inside the smallest cog.  If you have a 7 speed freewheel, the central area will NOT spin as the sprockets rotate.  Conversely, if you rotate a cassette attached to a freehub, you'll see the lock ring will rotate along with the cogs.  Then, it's a matter of determining the brand of freewheel or cassette and selecting the appropriate tool to interface with it. The Park Tool site linked above will have much to offer in the way of details regarding this.

*The 10 speed road rear derailleur RD-4700 (Tiagra) is an exception to this rule. It utilizes a pull ratio designed for 11 speed road rear derailleurs.

Answer (score 2):

From MTB component families, anything up to 9-speed is cross compatible with your 7 speed shifters, so you can choose a derailleur from Altus,Acera,Alivio groupsets. Also road oriented groupsets Claris and Sora are compatible.

If you're willing to look for second hand components, you could use also higher tier 8 or 9-speed MTB components. Simple way to identify what cable pull they use, would be a "Mega 9" sign somewhere on the 9-speed, versus a "Dyna-Sys" sign on the 10 speed stuff which is not compatible with your shifters.

I personally would look for older new-old-stuff Deore groupset e.g. RD-M592, there is a significant difference in build quality between the cheaper groupsets and Deore. On the other hand there is not so much difference between Deore and the higher tier groupsets like SLX or XT.

Answer (score 0):

The best derailleurs with this pull ratio are the RD-M950 XTR derailleur, or the RD-7900 Dura Ace derailleur. These are pretty much the pinnacle of engineering for this type. Neither has been made for a while.

Did you mean a different type of “best”?